# How to get information from database into columns and rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

well, I have already posted it, but I didn't explain it properly, so I deleted the older post, and in this post,
I'm gonna explain everything in detail.

In this picture you can see my database diagram.

[Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4M0Y.png)

I only gonna use 3 tables namely:

- tbl_transacciones
- tbl_componentes
- tbl_lineas

The information that I want to show in the SQL Query is like this:

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVseB.png)

The quantitys of each linear column, is the SUM of all quantity that i have in tbl_transacciones with the same relationships.

For example, if in tbl_transacciones i have
Some component, of some line, with X quantity, i want to show in my sql query, the sum of all components that have the same relationship, i hope that you can understand me, because my english is not so good, so i really hope that you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUM the Cantidad when the Linea = 1, 2, or 3.

```
SELECT c.Description
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN l.Nombre = 1
                THEN t.Cantidad
            END) "Linea_1"
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN l.Nombre = 2
                THEN t.Cantidad
            END) "Linea_2"
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN l.Nombre = 3
                THEN t.Cantidad
            END) "Linea_3"
FROM tbl_components c
LEFT JOIN tbl_transacciones t ON t.IdComponente = c.IdComponente
LEFT JOIN tbl_lineas l ON l.IdLinea = t.IdLinea
GROUP BY c.Description
```